# How to pass multiple arguments to one function?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project for school, and i'm trying to use 2 parameters in a function, but they are from 2 different functions. I have no clue how i can use them both.

What i'm trying to do is to actually use the code in showCityInfo in the function handleClickImg, but in order to do that i need the data 'city'
which is passed onto showCityInfo from the function getCityInfo, where the data is collected from my php.

So in short, i want to use the data 'city' and 'marker(=e.currentTarget)' in a function to do the following code i put in bold

```js
{
  const init = () => {

    let radiobutton = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');
    radiobutton.forEach(r => {
      r.addEventListener("change", changeOpacity);
      let $heart = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar > svg');

      $heart.forEach(h => {
        h.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
      })

      document.documentElement.classList.add('has-js');

      const $input = document.querySelector(`.world_form`);
      console.log($input);
      if ($input) {
        $input.addEventListener(`change`, handleChangeFilter);
      }
    });

    $markers = document.querySelectorAll('.world_map > img');
    console.log($markers);
    $markers.forEach(marker => {
      marker.addEventListener('click', handleClickImg);
    })

  }

  const handleChangeFilter = e => {
    const alignment = e.target.value;
    console.log(alignment);
    const path = window.location.href.split(`?`)[0];
    const qs = `?alignment=${alignment}`;
    getCityInfo(`${path}${qs}`);
  };

  const getCityInfo = async url => {
    console.log(url);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json'
      })
    });
    const city = await response.json();
    console.log(city);
    window.history.pushState({}, ``, url);
    showCityInfo(city);
  };
  const showCityInfo = city => { **
    const $parent = document.querySelector(`.contact_wrapper`);
    $parent.innerHTML = ``;
    $parent.innerHTML += `<p class="contact_info"><span>email:</span> Carvee${city.name}@hotmail.com</p>
    <p class="contact_info"><span>tel:</span> ${city.tel} 476 03 51 07</p>` **
  };

  const handleClickImg = e => {
    marker = e.currentTarget;
    console.log(marker);



    if (marker.id == city.city_code) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass 2 values to a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936749/pass-2-values-to-a-javascript-function)

Comment: I think what you're attempting is [currying a type of functional programming](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983)

Answer (score 0):

In case you only have to compare a city and a marker at a time, I think what you should do is declare two global variables outside of the functions to store the city and marker data and be able to access and compare them anywhere.

```
//...

let city, marker;

const getCityInfo = async url => {
  console.log(url);
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: new Headers({
      Accept: 'application/json'
    })
  });
  city = await response.json();
  console.log(city);
  window.history.pushState({}, ``, url);
  showCityInfo();
};

const showCityInfo = () => {
  const $parent = document.querySelector(`.contact_wrapper`);
  $parent.innerHTML = ``;
  $parent.innerHTML += `<p class="contact_info"><span>email:</span> Carvee${city.name}@hotmail.com</p><p class="contact_info"><span>tel:</span> ${city.tel} 476 03 51 07</p>`
};

const handleClickImg = e => {
  marker = e.currentTarget;
  console.log(marker);

  if (marker.id == city.city_code) {

  }
}
```